# sharing data among sibling components in a data grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

How can I pass data among sibling components? Lets say I have a sort of a data entry grid that looks like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of frm.controls.items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
   <td><input type="text" formControlName="id" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" formControlName="name" /></td>
</tr>
```

And let's say, there is some typescript that gets triggered either on `valueChanges` or a `focusout` event that handles the data entered in each of these fields. My question is, if I need to access the `id` data in focusout of the `name` field. How can I do that?

```
onNameFocusout = function(nameControl) {
  //get a handle of id control for the ROW that this name control belongs to
```

So all I have access to is the `name` control for some row and I need the `id` control for the same row.

I can think of a couple of different ways to do this:

1. In the html of the name control, pass the id control in the focus out event. Something like `<input type="text" formControlName="name" onNameFocusout="(frm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.id, frm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name)" />`
2. Use a data sharing service. Any values entered in grid are also available on the data sharing service to be retrieved by any component. This still requires knowing the index of the row to retrieve the data from.

Any suggestions on how this can be done in a better way or either one of these methods should work fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should able to get the value on blur:

**Template:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of frm.get('items'); let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
   <td><input type="text" formControlName="id" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" (blur)="onBlur(frm.get('items.' + i + '.id'))" formControlName="name" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Component class:**

```
onBlur(control: FormControl) {
   let value = control.value;
   // value = value of id
}
```